# Is my SSD broken, or something wrong with my OS? Can so help me interprete the smartctl output?

Tags: boot, shutdown, ssd, fsck, smart

I sometimes have the issue that ubuntu wont shut down correctly. Everytime this happens i need to run a manual fsck  before i can boot again.

The smartctl short tests are completing without any errors, but the extended one failes because of a "Fatal or unknown error".
My SSD is around 1.5 years old.

My main-question ist wether its the fault of the ssd or maybe the fault of the os. Do i have to replace the ssd in that case?

And besides that id still be interested in knowing what the errors in the smartctl check say :)

I have seen similar questions but without a final working answer. And an automatic fsck is cool, but wouldnt solve my problem :)

Thanks a lot :)

[failed shutdown output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB4rs.jpg)

systemctl -x output:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-51-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SSD PLUS 1000GB
Serial Number:    190532804063
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 8b922495a
Firmware Version: UH5100RL
User Capacity:    1.000.207.286.272 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Oct 19 00:55:01 2020 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  57) A fatal error or unknown test error
                    occurred while the device was executing
                    its self-test routine and the device 
                    was unable to complete the self-test 
                    routine.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x15) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 182) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    5064
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    477
165 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    231
166 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    1
167 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
168 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    3
169 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    1809
170 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
171 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
172 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
173 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
174 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    125
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    41
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   065   059   000    -    35 (Min/Max 13/59)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    283469152322
232 Available_Reservd_Space PO--CK   100   100   005    -    100
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    790
234 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    3614
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ----CK   100   100   000    -    1492
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ----CK   100   100   000    -    636
244 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   000   100   ---    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      1  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O     16  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL,SL  VS       2  Device vendor specific log
0xa3-0xa4  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa7       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       3  Device vendor specific log

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (16 sectors)
Device Error Count: 43
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 43 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5061 hours (210 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 01 5d cc 80 a0 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     05:22:04.063  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:52.801  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     00:00:46.940  READ LOG EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:46.849  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:38.770  FLUSH CACHE EXT

Error 42 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5055 hours (210 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 04 00 00 01 5d cc 84 a0 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:52.801  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     00:00:46.940  READ LOG EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:46.849  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:38.770  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     00:00:58.502  READ LOG EXT

Error 41 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5055 hours (210 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 01 5d cc 80 a0 00  Error: UNC

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     00:00:46.940  READ LOG EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:46.849  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:38.770  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     00:00:58.502  READ LOG EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     00:00:58.422  FLUSH CACHE EXT

Warning! SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
Error 40 [63] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 43  9d+22:36:33.459  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42  6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Error 39 [62] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33  9d+22:36:33.459  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32  6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Error 38 [61] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 23  9d+22:36:33.459  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22  6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 21  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Error 37 [60] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 43981 hours (1832 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 13  9d+22:36:33.459  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12  6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Warning! SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
Error 36 [59] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 43  9d+22:36:33.459  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42  6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Fatal or unknown error        90%      5061         0
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5060         -
# 3  Extended offline    Fatal or unknown error        90%      4923         0
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4859         -
# 5  Short offline       Self-test routine in progress 70%      4859         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

SCT Commands not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4             477  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            5064  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6      3129152158  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x028  6      1335439411  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x038  6            5065  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              35  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1               -  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              58  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              25  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              43  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              43  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              95  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1               0  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0009  2            3  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            4  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
```

Comment: It looks like a SATA drive cable failure (re-seat cable if you can), or a SanDisk SSD failure. In Windows, go to https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15108 and download/run their "Dashboard" software, run tests, see if there's a firmware update available.

Comment: I am going to agree with @heynnema here.  I have seen this with my drives in my system I use as a NAS with a RAID 5 in it.  I purchased locking sata cables and all the errors I was getting cleared up and I have not had any issues with the drives since.

Answer (score 0):

> My main-question ist wether its the fault of the ssd or maybe the fault of the os. Do i have to replace the ssd in that case?

It's the SSD. The best course of action is to immediately backup your treasured stuff and decide what you are going to do about replacing the SSD.